# WNetAddConnection2 fails with error code 1326 in some sites while net use succeeds

Tags: c#, network-programming

I used a small console app in c#, the code was basically harvested from some site whose url I forgot (so sorry for the author!), to test Windows Networking API WNetAddConnection2 to list files in a specified folder in UNC format. The code worked for most of the cases. Specifically, it worked in many machines in my office and in most of client sites. However, in a particular client site, the app failed with error code 1326 (bad name or password), sometimes with error code 86 (bad password). In this particular client site, "net use" succeeded. Therefore, it appeared that somehow WNetAddConnection2 returned a misleading error code.

I have tried to change the Local Policies "Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level" to "LM and NTLM – use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated" and "LM and NTLM", and still failed.

I also tried to open firewall port 445, 137, 139. The problem still remained.

public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
{
    readonly string _networkName;

```
public NetworkConnection(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
{
    _networkName = networkName;

    var netResource = new NetResource
    {
        Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
        ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
        DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
        RemoteName = networkName
    };

    var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
        ? credentials.UserName
        : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

    var result = WNetAddConnection2(
        netResource,
        credentials.Password,
        userName,
        0);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");
    }
}

~NetworkConnection()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
}

[DllImport("mpr.dll")]
private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
    string password, string username, int flags);

[DllImport("mpr.dll")]
private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
    bool force);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope : int
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
};

public enum ResourceType : int
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```

}

Help on either how to make our code work like "net use", or how to relax the potential network constraints imposed by the client site, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is the url of the source: https://gist.github.com/AlanBarber/92db36339a129b94b7dd.

Comment: I found the solution. Before calling WNetAddConnection2, call WNetCancelConnection2 first, then the problem was solved.